# Cannot enable "Remove data from the external data range before saving the workbook"

Tags: excel, ssas, pivot-table

I want to clear the cache of a PivotTable report which is attached to a SSAS cube. It should be easy, in the connection definition there is a checkbox which should serve this exact purpose:

> "Remove data from the external data range before saving the workbook"

(see also: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Refresh-connected-imported-data-e76a38b0-e2e1-400b-9f2f-c87b9b18c092)

Unfortunately the checkbox is grayed out and I could not find a way to activate it. I am aware that I could solve this with VBA or with an extension, but the preferred way should be to be able to activate this checkbox.

The server is Microsoft SQL Server 2014, enterprise edition, version 12.0.2000.8

Comment: Did you find an answer to this, I have the same issue.

Comment: unfortunately not. I do not even have this SSAS environment available anymore (project is long over).

Answer (score 2):

This is old, but still an issue. Another place to look is in the pivot table options. Right-click in the pivot table, choose "PivotTable Options...", go to the Data tab, uncheck "Save source data with file."

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I didn't have success with that Excel feature either so I wrote this Excel add-in feature. Give it a try and see if that's what you are looking for:
http://olappivottableextend.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Clear%20PivotTable%20Cache&referringTitle=Home

Comment: Hi Greg. I already tried your extension, but there are two problems: 1. You have to give each pivot its own connection, which is incompatible with my client needs: she need slicer which act on all the pivots at the same time (and this is possible only if the pivots use the same connection). 2. your extension work with pivot and not with graph (alone) and I have some graph without pivot.          +1 for the good work on the extension but the problem is not solved.

Comment: Good feedback. Thanks. I added that as a feature request: https://olappivottableextend.codeplex.com/workitem/65011#

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the option gets disabled when the connection manager includes "Multiple Tables", i.e. when the ODC connection has a command type "TableCollection".

`<odc:CommandType>TableCollection</odc:CommandType>`

Below is the option to avoid using in order to have the "Remove data from the external data range before saving the workbook" check box available.

[image: Highlighted "Enable selection of multiple tables" text]

Answer (score -1):

just check the box "Refresh data when opening the file"

[image]

Comment: That option remains grayed out for me using a power pivot connection at least.